# unitary representations of Kac-Moody algebras

Tags: kac-moody-algebras

Is there an easily accessible text containing a detailed description and derivation of all unitary representations of affine Kac-Moody algebras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter III of the lecture notes on [Kac-Moody and Virasoro algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1287) by Antony Wasserman (2010) might well be what you are looking for:

> This course develops the representation theory of affine Kac–Moody
>   algebras and the Virasoro algebra. These infinite–dimensional Lie
>   algebras play an important role in string theory and conformal field
>   theory; they are the Lie algebras of the loop groups and
>   diffeomorphism group of the circle. We adopt a unitary viewpoint and
>   use supersymmetry as the main technique.